# Libgdx: Group/Stage for 3d

Tags: 3d, libgdx, listener, stage

I'm using libgdx 1.2 and after a lot of searching I've not found answer on question
"Is there Group/Stage-similar implementation for 3d (decals, models)".

Basically what I need:
- group decals (and maybe models) (e.g. as Group with Actors in 2d);
- add listeners on decals (and maybe models) (e.g. as for Stage in 2d)

Please notify if this has been already implemented (or in progress).

Comment: https://github.com/pyros2097/Scene3d Other than that, nope.

Comment: @noone Thanks! It seams it's what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Scene3d for libgdx:
https://github.com/pyros2097/Scene3d
Thanks to **pyros2097** for this module and [noone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816356/noone) for hint.

Comment: however this lib doesn't have support for Decal :(